# Why isnt my immediately invoked function setting my selected elements after the next button is clicked on the calendar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6, web-deployment

I have been trying to to complete this calendar for the past few days and cant seem to figure the issue. mysFunction() allows the user to put in events into the calendar but for this function to be called I made an immediately invoked function to set the attributes of all li elements with the class cl-day with onclick = "mysFunction()" initially everything is set but once you go forward or backward a month it all goes away and the function is no longer tied to each cell.

Is there a way to refresh the function on each click? I'm out of ideas on how to fix this issue.

I have a jsfiddle

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/p50nfpeh/

I think the issue is that the function isn't being executed again when i click the next button to change the month on the calendar.

```
         (function() {
         var titles = document.querySelectorAll(".cld-day");
             var i = titles.length;
             while (i--) {
             titles[i].setAttribute("onclick", "mysFunction()");
         }

          })();
```

Comment: What exactly does that fiddle not do? What is the problem here?

Comment: how are you generating the `li`'s for each day?

Comment: the fiddle is completely useless because it tries to reference JS files that it can't access. The whole point of a JSFiddle is that it should be runnable.

Comment: The problem is when you go to the next month and try to add an event you cant do it anymore. The button to the right opens the calendar after doing so click in any cell and you can add events correct? After that go to the next month may and try to add an event it doesn work anymore :(

Comment: Im using the query selector. All of the elements are created within the javascript. The query selector document.querySelectorAll(".cld-day"); has all li elements then the attribute onclick is created and set to mysFunction()

Comment: oh crap ill fix the fiddle link sorry

Comment: Here https://jsfiddle.net/rGsuStud/p50nfpeh/2/

Comment: All of the script is in the Javascript part which is lower left box

Comment: In part of your js which generates new days for each month the `Option.EventClick` is undefined. Pretty sure that should be your function name

Comment: In this case, your IIFE is processed only when the page is first loaded into the browser. If you wanted to use it again when the month is changed, declare it in your existing function or assign it a name and call it

Comment: Oh snap your right can i tie my immediately invoked function to this? Should I what is best practice?

Comment: I would just copy it into your existing function. everything else works